# How can I use Ubuntu on a Windows 7 pre-installed system?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to try Ubuntu on my laptop which already has Windows 7.

How can I try them without installing them? Are there any ways to use them directly from a USB stick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use wubi installer ( search for wubi ), this allows you to install ubuntu on windows 7 as a program which you can uninstall if required easily
2. You can boot from ubuntu CD it gives you an option to try it without installing ( as a live CD)
3. you can install on vmware or virtual box

Comment: i not have any CD to burn but i have a little pen-drive 4GB. how  i can use it for install linux

Comment: Use a virtualisation system, such as VirtualBox or VMWare Player - they work with ISO images, so no need to play with CD writing or pen drives.

Comment: @user33631 Have a look at [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - writes USB-sticks with various linux distros

Answer (score 0):

If it is a laptop as opposed to a netbook, go for desktop edition.

I believe you can boot from an Ubuntu CD into Ubuntu without installation, known as a Live CD.

From a USB Stick https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Answer (score 0):

You may want to install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) and install Ubuntu in it. it is free, and this is best when you do not want to change the host machine and try multiple operating systems.

And in most cases, you can still continue after your "trial".

Answer (score 0):

Make a USB stick with the Ubuntu image on it, use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to download and install the image on your USB stick. Boot up your laptop from the USB stick and you can use it as you would a normally but it does not install anything on your hard drive whatsoever.